# Can cloudrail be used serverless?

Tags: cloudrail

Cloudrail seems perfect to simplify interaction of a web page with e.g. google drive or other cloud service.

And this may be due to my lack of understanding and lack of knowledge of web development and Node.js, but can cloudrail be used serverless?
Or in other words can cloudrail be used on a stand-alone html page on a local computer (i.e. served by the filesystem instead of a server) and be made to access google drive or even work with an off-line mode while on a stand-alone html page (which may later sync with google drive)?

The reason being I would like to design a simple mobile app that accesses the cloud (fine so far) that is mirrored as a simple portable web page that can sit anywhere (desktop/laptop/mobile/USB stick) and is not served by any server but simply loaded from the local filesystem.

If not cloudrail, what other technology might I need to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can use it as a standalone website the way you describe it. You might be able to realize your use case though by e.g. using CloudRail's Nodejs SDK with Electron. This allows you to create an application very similar to a website with Javascript while still giving your users just one file that runs pretty much everywhere.

Comment: Thank you this might be a viable option, although I was trying to find a way that does not require any installation on a desktop computer. Maybe I just need to bite the bullet.